# Elements of $\mathbb{F}_7^*/\mathbb{F}_7^{*3}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields, quotient-group

I think I have forgotten some basic group theory, but I am having hard time representing the elements from $\mathbb{F}_7^*/\mathbb{F}_7^{*3}$, where $\mathbb{F}_7^{*3}$ denotes all elements that are cubes in $\mathbb{F}_7^*$. I have figured out that $\mathbb{F}_7^{*3} = \{\bar{1},\bar{6}\}$ and hence $\mathbb{F}_7^*/\mathbb{F}_7^{*3}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. However, I am looking for representative elements from $\mathbb{F}_7^*$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: given two elements of $\mathbb{F}_7^*$, how could you tell if they represent the same element in the quotient group? Remember, this is the same as asking if they lie in the same left coset of $\mathbb{F}_7^{*3}$.

Comment: Thanks! I just wrote everything down and it all followed nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The group $\Bbb F_7^\ast$, as group of units of a finite field, is a cyclic group and it has order 6.
It is generated by every primitive root modulo $7$, for example, 3.
Since $3^3\equiv 6\pmod 7$, follows that the quotient group $\Bbb F_7^\ast/\Bbb F_7^{\ast 3}$ has representatives $1,3,9$.